# Join split words and punctuation with punctuation in the right place

Tags: python, join, split, punctuation

So I tried using `join()` after splitting a string into words and punctuation but it joins the string with a space in between the word and punctuation.

`b = ['Hello', ',', 'who', 'are', 'you', '?']

c = " ".join(b)`

But that returns:
`c = 'Hello , who are you ?'`

and I want:
`c = 'Hello, who are you?'`

Comment: Does calling the method on an empty string work?

Comment: @CBroe: No, because you then get `'Hello,whoareyou?'` instead..

Comment: Yeah, right. So a simple join won’t do, because there’s different “types” of data, words and punctuation. So I guess one would need a self-written method that first checks which of those it is, and then concatenates the parts with a space or no space accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could join on the punctuation first:

```
def join_punctuation(seq, characters='.,;?!'):
    characters = set(characters)
    seq = iter(seq)
    current = next(seq)

    for nxt in seq:
        if nxt in characters:
            current += nxt
        else:
            yield current
            current = nxt

    yield current

c = ' '.join(join_punctuation(b))
```

The `join_punctuation` generator yields strings with any following punctuation already joined on:

```
>>> b = ['Hello', ',', 'who', 'are', 'you', '?']
>>> list(join_punctuation(b))
['Hello,', 'who', 'are', 'you?']
>>> ' '.join(join_punctuation(b))
'Hello, who are you?'
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this after you get the result, not full, but works...

```
c = re.sub(r' ([^A-Za-z0-9])', r'\1', c)
```

Output:

```
c = 'Hello , who are you ?'
>>> c = re.sub(r' ([^A-Za-z0-9])', r'\1', c)
>>> c
'Hello, who are you?'
>>>
```

Comment: Good one, except that `re.sub(r' (?=\W)', '', c)` would be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> punc = set(punctuation) # or whatever special chars you want
>>> b = ['Hello', ',', 'who', 'are', 'you', '?']
>>> ''.join(w if set(w) <= punc else ' '+w for w in b).lstrip()
'Hello, who are you?'
```

This adds a space before words in `b` which aren't made up entirely of punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the answer of Martijn Pieters♦](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950837/9288003), I made a little generalization for languages with punctuation signs that can also be at the start of a word.

```py
from string import punctuation


def join_punctuation(
    seq,
    characters_after=punctuation,
    characters_before="¡¿"
):
    characters_after = set(characters_after)
    characters_before = set(characters_before)
    seq = iter(seq)
    current = next(seq)

    for nxt in seq:
        if current in characters_before:
            current += nxt
        elif nxt in characters_after:
            current += nxt
        else:
            yield current
            current = nxt

    yield current
```

It would work the same way:

```py
>>> b = ["Hola", ",", "¿", "Qué", "tal", "?"]
>>> list(join_punctuation(b))
['Hola,', '¿Qué', 'tal?']
>>> " ".join(join_punctuation(b))
'Hola, ¿Qué tal?'
```

Answer (score -1):

How abt

```
c = " ".join(b).replace(" ,", ",")
```

Comment: You need to do the same for the `?` question mark, and there may be more types of punctuation.