# Python join punctuation correctly

Tags: python, list

I have a list split into words and punctuation:

> list2 = ['"', 'Stop', 'right', 'there', '"', 'said', 'George', '.']

I want to have the list join to make:

> '"Stop right there" said George.'

But is there an efficient method of joining the 1st speech mark to the next element, and the other punctuation (in this list) to the previous?

I must also mention that the list can be of any words and punctuation, so it could just as well be:

> ['Dilly' 'Dally', '(', 'it's', 'a', 'hard', 'life', '!', ')']

or anything else.

For confirmation that list would be:

> 'Dilly Dally (it's a hard life!)'

Comment: So to be clear, you are looking for an efficient way to put spaces between words but not between punctuation characters? if so, perhaps you should put that explicit question into the title and/or body of your question, since otherwise it's anyone's guess as to what you mean by "correctly".

Comment: It's more complicated than that. How can the program be expected to tell whether a particular punctuation should be joined to the word on the left, on the right, or both?

Comment: This question have already being done here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950672/join-split-words-and-punctuation-with-punctuation-in-the-right-place)

Comment: So this is kind of the inverse of what http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/ can do.

Comment: glibdud is right, I couldn't think of an appropriate title to give my problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Dinidiniz Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

Comment: @D.Kang , you can use `''.join(list2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one built-in string join

```
In [144]: ' '.join(list2)
Out[144]: '" Stop right there " said George .'
In [145]: ''.join(list2)
Out[145]: '"Stoprightthere"saidGeorge.'
```

It's not right, but it's the only thing that can be described as 'efficient'.

I can imagine using `regex` expressions to remove the undesired blanks from `Out[144]`.   Alternatively, scan `list2` and combine the punctuations with the neighboring string:

```
In [146]: list3 = ['"Stop', 'right', 'there"', 'said', 'George.']
In [147]: ' '.join(list3)
Out[147]: '"Stop right there" said George.'
```

There may be some add-on packages that handle this kind of text formatting.  But to basic Python, strings with punctuation characters are not different from other strings.

A comment [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950672/join-split-words-and-punctuation-with-punctuation-in-the-right-place).  Using Pieter's function:

```
In [150]: ' '.join(join_punctuation(list2))
Out[150]: '" Stop right there " said George.'
```

Correcting it to include quote:

```
In [152]: ' '.join(join_punctuation(list2))
Out[152]: '" Stop right there" said George.'
```

doesn't get both quotes right. It joins the punctuation with the preceding string. `()` would have the same issue.  In any case, that's the kind of processing that you will need.

---

It's easy to class `(` as punctuation that should join to the right, and `)` as joining to the left.  But distinguishing between left and right join for `"` might require looking a a broader picture.  The first `"` in the sentence should be right join, the next left and so on.   And I suspect that even that won't be robust.

Comment: Thanks! Not the full answer I was looking for, but still very helpful :)